# Strange Ubuntu linux boot behaviour

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, boot

I've recently installed Ubuntu 9.10 on a desktop machine as the only OS. If put in a hibernate, it wakes up normally, but if turned off completely, after turning on there is no "beep" sound from BIOS and HD lamp blinks for a while then stops.

When I hit reset in that state, it boots normally. What is going on and how could I fix it?

Comment: Is that a new computer or did was it up and running with some other OS for some time?

Comment: Had windows before, and it booted normally. It's 2-3 years old.

Comment: Is the function you're using really hibernate? Or is it suspend?

Comment: both suspend to ram, and hibernate work ok.

Answer (score 2):

I expect your BIOS to not be finding the hard disk drive because it's not powering up fast enough. That would explain why it works after a reset.

If you enter the BIOS, does the boot run normally after you exit it? Have you tried with another hard disk?